Joining subquery from different database in Laravel
I'm attempting to join a subquery into a main query using the Laravel Query Builder in a context similar to the example below. I assumed that the main query would recognize this by specifying the database and table used by the subquery. However, Laravel throws the following SQL error:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
'data_source2.data_table1' doesn't exist

I've tried prefixing the source query with "data_source1", but I still encounter the same error as shown above.
$source_query = DB::connection('data_source1')
    ->table('data_table1')
    ->select(DB::raw('
        SUM(data_table1.value) as value
    '))
   
$data = DB::connection('data_source2')
    ->table('data_table2')
    ->joinSub($source_query, 'source_query', function ($join) {
        $join->on('data_table2.hour', '=', 'source_query.hour');
    })
    ->where('date', '=', $date)
    ->select(DB::raw('
        source_query.value as value,
    '))
    ->get();


In the data_source2 connection, is there a database table called data_table1?

there is not a table called data_table1 in data_source2 @AntonyMN

I have ended up figuring it out so for anyone else who comes across this, if you want to use joinSub() when the queries use base tables in different databases
use the following in the subquery you will be joining in:
$source_query = DB::table('data_source1.data_table1')

rather than:
$source_query = DB::connection('data_source1')
    ->table('data_table1')

